# read xml file having namespace in root

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the values of each element from the XML file having namespace in root element but no luck.

The xml file looks like

[image]

I have written some C# code using linq but could not get any result.

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileFullPath);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.springframework.net";

var elements = from data in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Record")
               select new
               {
                   firstName = (string)data.Element(ns + "FirstName").Value,
                   lastName = (string)data.Element(ns + "LastName").Value,
                   id = (string)data.Element(ns + "ID").Value,
                };

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.firstName);
    Console.WriteLine(element.lastName);
    Console.WriteLine(element.id);
}
```

I want to have result like

```
Ram
Brown
22148868
```

Can anyone suggest or edit my code please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your code so that it's formatted nicely - please use the preview to do so yourself when asking future questions. It would also be useful to show the XML as *text* within your post rather than as an image. (For example, that makes it easy for other users to copy it into an XML file and test the code.) Your code effectively expects that there could be multiple records in a file, but it's actually the root element... do you have an example of what a file with multiple records would look like?

Answer (score 3):

Your XML elements are *not* in the `http://www.springframework.net` namespace - they're in an empty namespace, which is why they've got `xmlns=""` in there.

You also have a typo - you've got two `XDocument` variables - one is `xdoc` (an empty document) and one is `doc` (the document you've loaded). Your current code is querying the empty one, which obviously isn't going to work. I suggest you get rid of that variable entirely.

So you'd want to change your code to:

```
var elements = from data in doc.Descendants(ns + "Record")
               select new
               {
                   firstName = (string) data.Element("FirstName"),
                   lastName = (string) data.Element("LastName"),
                   id = (string) data.Element("ID"),
                };
```

Note that I kept the `ns` part for the `Record` element, because that *is* in the namespace. I also removed the use of the `Value` property - you *either* need to cast the element *or* you need to use the `Value` property, but not both.

Comment: @User: It doesn't help that you haven't updated your post to include the XML as text. I've just had to type all that in myself by hand in order to reproduce the problem and help you. I'll edit my answer, but please help us to help you by editing your post to include the XML as *text*. It would also help if you would show the current output - which is actually that it's not picking up your record *at all*.